# Why is auto backup not working consistently for one of two client PCs on Windows Server Essentials 2016?

Tags: windows-server-2016

I have a Windows Server Essentials 2016 setup that has been working fine for months to backup two laptops.  In the last month or so, one doesn't usually do an automatic backup overnight.  I'll use these names for discussion purposes:

- WSE2016: Server
- PCFine: Laptop where automatic nightly backup works consistently
- PCNotFine: the problem PC

For both, unless I've recently just done this, if I right-click on a PC in the Dashboard, Device window, select "Customize Backup for the Computer", then click on "Add or remove backup items", I get the following message:

> Backup cannot connect to the Windows Server Essentials Client Computer Management Service on your network computer.  (suggests restart)

If I close out of that then try it again, it works on both PCs.  I've noticed that when the Windows Server Essentials Client Computer Management Service on the client is not running (Manual - Trigger Start), I get the error message; After that message, the service starts allowing (I assume) the above steps to work.  Initiating a manual backup for PCNotFine starts the service and the backup completes successfully.

I checked server backup logs expecting to find some indication that an attempt to backup PCNotFine was initiated but failed but there was nothing that showed an attempt to backup that client.

I shut down the WSE server and both PCs while I was out of town for a week.  When I returned, I started all 3 and about 2-3 hours later both PCs were automatically backed up successfully.

PCNotFine and PCFine - Version  10.0.19045 Build 19045

1. Any idea what might be keeping PCNotFine from backing up automatically?
2. Is there any harm in changing the startup type for Windows Server Essentials Client Computer Management Service to automatic on that PC so it's always running?

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember what I was doing when the option to change this came up (maybe coming in through the launch pad) but I turned on the option to wake the problem computer for backup and since then automatic backup has worked fine.